# Warning: Guessing NAME [src] from current directory name

Tags: perl, makefile, mojolicious

When I run

```
perl Makefile.PL
```

I get

```
Warning: Guessing NAME [src] from current directory name.
```

This is not what I want. I generated this Makefile with

```
mojo generate makefile
```

It looks like,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
  VERSION   => '0.01',
  PREREQ_PM => {'Mojolicious' => '8.30'},
  test      => {TESTS => 't/*.t'}
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just updated the `WriteMakefile()` to add the missing `NAME`

```
WriteMakefile(
  NAME      => 'MyApp',
  ...
);
```

Comment: The documentation in fact says this is required, though apparently there is some fallback mechanism. https://perldoc.pl/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#NAME1